# Tracing in Spring Integration (Spring boot 3.0.9)

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I'm trying to use Spring integration: I receive a message via JMS and send it to Kafka:

```
@Override
protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
      return from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory).destination(mqInQueue))
             .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, message -> "Received JMS message: " + message.getPayload())
             .channel(channels -> MessageChannelFactory.create(channels, "request-channel-1"))
             .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).topic(kafkaOutTopic));
}
```

For checks I am send messages to MQ using POST request + JmsTemplate:

```
@PostMapping("/mq")
public String sentToMq(@RequestBody final String body) {
     jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(mqRequestQueue, body, m -> {
         final var span = tracer.startScopedSpan("jms-send");
         try {
             final var context = span.context();
             m.setStringProperty("b3", "%s-%s-%s".formatted(context.traceId(), context.spanId(), Boolean.TRUE.equals(context.sampled()) ? "1" : "0"));
         } finally {
             span.end();
         }

         return m;
     });
     return "done";
}
```

Everything works fine, except tracing. I'm set `b3` header manually before sending, but after receiving Spring Integration overrides it. What should I do to keep the incoming traceId?

Also I have next configuration:
`@EnableIntegrationManagement(observationPatterns = "*")`

```
    @Bean
    @GlobalChannelInterceptor(order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public ChannelInterceptor observationPropagationChannelInterceptor(final ObservationRegistry observationRegistry) {
        return new ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor(observationRegistry);
    }
```

Comment: Any chances to have a simple project from you to reproduce and play with? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I know where is the problem.
The `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` does not propagate its `registerObservationRegistry(ObservationRegistry)` down to the `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener`, therefore an `IntegrationObservation.HANDLER` does not restore a trace from that `b3` header.

An observation on the `MessageChannel` consult only with the current context and really populate a fresh `b3` header according to that current context.

Consider to use `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(AbstractMessageListenerContainer)` instead and use `AbstractMessageListenerContainer.setObservationRegistry()` to enable its `JmsObservationDocumentation.JMS_MESSAGE_PROCESS` consumer tracing.

For `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint`, please, raise a GH issue in Spring Integration.

Comment: Here is the fix I've mentioned before needed to be done on Spring Integration side: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/8740

Answer (score 0):

just to add a simple example to the response by @Artem-Bilan (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77108741/23224272)

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow yourFlow(ObservationRegistry observationRegistry, JsonObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper) {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(
                Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                        Jms.container(activeMQConnectionFactory, "queueName")
                                .concurrency(concurrency)
                                .observationRegistry(observationRegistry)
                                .sessionTransacted(true)
                                .getObject()
                ))
                .transform(new JsonToObjectTransformer(ClassName.class, jsonObjectMapper))
                .channel("channelName")
                .get();
    }
```

you can inject those objects any other way - this was chosen for brevity